# jQuery - show contextmenu after doing event.preventDefault

Tags: javascript, jquery, contextmenu, preventdefault

I'm overriding the context menu (only if specific elements are rightclicked). I do this by binding the contextmenu and then doing a event.preventDefault().

The problem I have is I'm running some logic after the event.preventDefault() and if a specific senario is true I want to show the original contextmenu not a custom one.

So my question is, how can I show the *default* context menu after I already did preventDefault.

```
$(document).bind("contextmenu", function (event) {
    if(event.shiftKey || event.ctrlKey) {
        return;
    }
    attr = event.target.attributes
    if(!attr.length){ //if we don't have any attributes we automatically know this isn't the data-role="taskName" so return
        return;
    }
    val = event.target.attributes[0].nodeValue;
    if(!val.length){
        return; //we do have attributes but if that attribute doesn't equal taskName then return
    }


    switch(val){
        case 'taskName':
            //code here
            break;
        case 'individualTaskNote_contexTrigger':
            //read above
            break;
        case 'description':
            //read above
            //if we are currently in edit mode we don't allow right clicks to go into edit mode
            if(helper_bool_descriptionAlreadyInEditMode){
                return;
            }
            break;
        default:
            return;
            break;
    }

    // Avoid the real one
    event.preventDefault();


    switch(val){
        case 'taskName':
            //irreverent code here
            break;
/*********************/
/*********************/
/*********************/
        case 'individualTaskNote_contexTrigger':
            var $contextMenu    = $customMenuNotesComment;
            var $parentNode     = $(event.target.parentNode);

            if($parentNode.hasClass('alert')){
                //correct element
                //console.log('golden');
            }else{
                if($parentNode.attr('id') == 'notes_theNotes'){
                    //idk what to do
                    //console.log('here');
                    $temp = $(event.target);

                    //console.log($temp);

                    if($temp.hasClass('alert')){
                        $parentNode = $temp;
                        //console.log('yess');
                    }else{
                        $parentNode = $(event.target).parents('alert');
                        //console.log('find parent');
                    }
                }else{
                    $parentNode = $parentNode.parents('.alert');
                    //console.log('else');
                }
            }

            helper_int_contexMenu_taskIDRightClicked    = $parentNode.attr('data-note-id');

            if(typeof helper_obj_notesCommentsAlreadyInEditMode[helper_int_contexMenu_taskIDRightClicked] != 'undefined' && helper_obj_notesCommentsAlreadyInEditMode[helper_int_contexMenu_taskIDRightClicked]){
                //event.contextmenu();
                /* HERE IS WHERE i WANT TO SHOW THE ORIGINAL CONTEXT MENU, IF THIS IS TRUE SHOW DEFAULT CONTEXT MENU */
                return; //if we are in edit mode let's no longer continue!
            }


            $parentNode.addClass('taskRename-highlight');


            // Show contextmenu
            if ($parentNode.hasClass("highlight-task")){ //if the currently right clicked task is currently highlighted
                //this task is currently highlighted, so we want to show our display notification menu
                $contextMenu.find('li[data-action="second"]').show();
            }

            if($parentNode.attr('data-created-by') == loggedInUser){
                $contextMenu.find('li[data-action="third"]').show();
            }

            break;
/*********************/
/*********************/
/*********************/
        case 'description':
            //irreverent code here
            break;
    }




    $contextMenu.finish().toggle(350).

    // In the right position (the mouse)
    css({
        top:    (event.pageY + 1) + "px",
        left:   (event.pageX - 2) + "px"
    });

});
```

as you can see, towards the bottom of the snip-it, I have a comment where I want to show the default context menu. I thought maybe event.contextmenu() would work, it did not.

Anyone have any suggestions
(I know I can mode the event.preventDefault() down below the code snip-it comment and that will work but I want the event.preventDefault() to be executed as soon as possible, moving that is a last resort.)

---

ANSWER

Per the comment stating you can't, the answer is to move event.preventDefault() to below the second switch statement. This way when we return it still shows the default because we haven't prevented it yet.

Comment: `how can I show the default context menu after I already did preventDefault.` You can't. You need to re-arrange your logic so that `preventDefault()` is only called when you want to cancel the click event.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I was hoping that wasn't the case. Thank you for the input and quick response!